# Prestashop call custom command on order complete

Tags: prestashop

In Prestashop does anyone know if it is possible to trigger a custom command on order complete?

The command I need to call is a python script on the same server.

Comment: there are some hook on prestashop in 1.5.4 you can take a look.
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.5

I am not sure you want sure you want to fire hook on order status update or complet or payment. So please go through the hook documentation and find your one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand [prestashop hooks](http://orddoc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Understanding+and+using+hooks).

You create a module that registers and uses the appropriate hook (something related to the orders).

In the hook code you use `shell_exec('your_python_script.py')`.